# Can't find an amazon element with jsoup (Java) because I have little knowledge with web development

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm currently trying to scrape amazon for a bunch of data.  I'm using jsoup to help me do this, and everything has gone pretty smoothly, but for some reason I can't figure out how to pull the current number of sellers selling new products.

Here's an example of the url I'm scraping : [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B006L7KIWG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006L7KIWG)

I want to extract "39 new" from the following below:

```
<div id="secondaryUsedAndNew" class="mbcOlp">
    <div class="mbcOlpLink">
        <a class="buyAction" href="/gp/offer-listing/B006L7KIWG/ref=dp_olp_new_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=new">
            39&nbsp;new
        </a> &nbsp;from&nbsp;
        <span class="price">$60.00</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

This project is the first time I've used jsoup, so the coding may be a bit iffy, but here are some of the things I have tried:

```
 String asinPage = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/" + getAsin();
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(asinPage).timeout(timeout).get();
.....  

  //get new sellers try one
                    Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
                    for (Element link : links) {
                       // System.out.println("Span olp:"+link.text());
                        String code = link.attr("abs:href");
                        String label = trim(link.text(), 35);
                        if (label.contains("new")) {
                            System.out.println(label + " : " + code);
                        }
                    }

    //get new sellers try one
                    Elements links = document.select("div.mbcOlpLink");
                    for (Element link : links) {
                       // System.out.println("Span olp:"+link.text());
                    }

    //about a million other failed attempts that you'll just have to take my word on.
```

I've been successful when scrape everything else I need on the page, but for some reason this particular element is being a pain, any help would be GREAT!  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
String s = document.select("div[id=secondaryUsedAndNew] a.buyAction").text.replace("&nbsp;"," ");
```

This should leave you "42 new" as it says on the page at this moment.

Hope this works for you!